# Return type of Table-Valued Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

If the return type of my Table-Valued function is one of my existing tables, say TBL, do I still need to write all column names, types and lengths in the function signature, or is there a way to say that this function returns table TBL?

A quick example: Say I have a table TBL with two fields (the actual table I'm working with is far wider):

```
TBL
{
    ID int NOT NULL
    Name varchar(100) NOT NULL
}
```

My Table-Valued function performs some complex filtering on the table and returns conforming rows without any column projections, i.e. entire rows are returned. Currently the function looks like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetHistory
(
   --some params
)
RETURNS 
@RetVal TABLE                             <<<<<
(                                         <<<<<
    ID int NOT NULL,                      <<<<<
    Name varchar(100) NOT NULL            <<<<<
)                                         <<<<<
AS
BEGIN
    --Logic here
    RETURN;
END
```

As you see, I am copying the entire structure of my table in the `RETURNS` clause. Is there a way so I could just tell SQL Server that this function returns TBL structure instead of writing all columns here? Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetHistory
(
   --some params
)
RETURNS 
@RetVal TBL                               <<<<<<<
AS
BEGIN
    --Logic here
    RETURN;
END
```

(Target platform is SQL Server 2008 R2 and above)

Comment: And just how would you expect the FUNCTION to deal with a change to the TBL definition?

Comment: @Blam: How do Views deal with the change in TBL definition?

Comment: Why are you asking me about views?   If you have a question about views then post another question.  That question is certainly not an answer to my question/

Comment: @Blam: You didn't get it, so I'll explain. When you make change in table definition, any views that depend upon it can become invalid, but that doesn't prevent you from making changes to the table, right? In other words, saying that "function's return type cannot be set to an existing table because table's definition can change" is similar to saying that "we should not be able to create views because their underlying table's definition can change". If DBA is changing a table, he should take care of the dependent functions/SPs. In the worst case the function will fail just like the view would.

Comment: Really ANY change to a table and any view that depends on it becomes invalid?  Wrong.  Really you want something as simple as changing column order in a table to break your function because you don't want to spend the effort to explicitly define the return type?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that unfortunately, Microsoft has not made it possible to do what you ask with a multi-statement table-value function, although the concept of a type that represents a table exists, and the syntax could have been exactly like your example, where TBL would have been defined with 'create type ... as table...(...)'. The syntax of the multi-statement function requires the table to be defined column by column and does not take a type.

So, while you can take advantage of the declared type that defines a table structure in other cases, such as the defining multiple table variables with the same structure, in the case of a multi-statement function you have to copy/paste the structure definition or specify it there column by column.

The responders and commenters so far seem to have no idea of the difference between a multi-statement table-value function and inline table-value function.

The example in the question is a multi-statement table-value function. Answer 1 suggests re-writing it as an inline function, but that assumes that it is possible and feasible to rewrite the particular function as an inline function. However, if the two types of functions were so interchangeable, they would not both exist. Each has its strengths and weaknesses, and each has its place.

I believe you also have the option to change the function to a stored procedure and return the result with a select statement and include the result in a query or insert it in a table (where you have to exec the stored procedure as part of the select or insert statement and declare the names of the columns). However, that in my humble opinion is so much uglier than the minor inelegance of having to declare the table structure in the function.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer and even more for correctly understanding the problem. Years have passed since I had the problem and posted the question, so I can't recall the exact details, but anyway this may help future landers.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetHistory()
RETURNS TABLE
AS

RETURN
    SELECT  ID, Name
    FROM    TableName
```

EF:

```
        var ee = new Entities();
        var c = ee.GetHistory().ToList;
```

ADO:

```
var conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {

                    string sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM dbo.GetHistory()";
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlSelect, conn);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
```

Comment: Really? Will client tools such as .NET DataSets correctly read the return type of this function (in the designer I mean)?

Comment: Also note that my function builds the query through string concatenation, so I'll not be able to write a query in front of `RETURN` keyword. Is that a problem?

Comment: @dotNET - "my function builds the query through string concatenation" - if you mean you're doing dynamic SQL, you've already taken a wrong turn - you can't `EXEC` from within a UDF.

Comment: Do not know what you mean but I've just verified in EF and it works.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: OMG

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: This doesn't work. SQL Server tells me that "Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client."

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: You're doing it through code. Open DataSet designer and try drag-dropping the UDF onto designer's surface.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: Plus the bigger issue is that the function body is multi-line. There are some IF-ELSE, so my `RETURN` keyword cannot follow a query immediately.

Comment: Then obviously you can not do this with functions. If you don't want to use inline function you should provide return table variable. Why not to use StoredProc instead?